# Как просуммировать строки с одинаковым полем?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица *Stag* (`PersonNumber, DataStart, DataFinish, Dolgnost, MestoRaboty`).

Например: в этой таблице есть такие строки

```
1, 2001-01-01, 2010-01-01, Менеджер, Банк

1, 2010-02-10, null, Менеджер, Отель
```

Я делаю процедуру, чтобы та выводила список людей, стаж которых, ну скажем более 10 лет...

null-я подразумеваю, что человек здесь работает и не уволен.

Исходя из этих двух строк, *стаж в сумме > 10!*
Как сделать так, что бы просматривались все строки с одним и тем же номером сотрудника и суммировались?

Использую `DATEDIFF` и `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, но не пойму как...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для MySQL запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT
    PersonNumber,
    SUM( -- Сумматор
        DATEDIFF( -- Разница между конечной и начальной датой
            IFNULL(DataFinish, CURDATE()), -- если дата = NULL, то берем текущую
            DataStart
        )
    ) / 365 AS count_years
FROM stag
GROUP BY PersonNumber -- Группируем по работникам
HAVING count_years > 10 -- Ограничиваем выборку теми чей стаж > 10 лет
```

Comment: спасибо!) тут вроде все понятно, но все равно не работает(((


'CURDATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: `CURDATE()` это функция в MySQL которая возвращает текущую дату. Если ты используешь другую СУБД то поищи там аналогичную.

Comment: спасибо, заработало!

Answer (score 1):

по мотивам такого кода

```
SELECT Manager
FROM Stag
HAVING SUM(DATEDIFF(year, ISNULL(DataFinish, GETDATE(), DataStart)>10
GROUP BY Manager
```

Comment: не понял(((
можно пояснить...
у меня все подчеркивается в строке после SUM...
year-это разница в годах, isnull-это если ячейка пуста? а дальше не пойму...getdate-что-то вроде текущей даты?

Comment: GROUP BY Manager наверно после FROM должен стоять...?

Comment: ну да конечно. если тэг указан sql, то я считаю речь об MS SQL и пишу на диалекте T-SQL

Comment: названия колонок и полный список полей, по которому группировать составляйте самостоятельно. у вас же не указаны первичные ключи

Comment: спасибо, все сделал!